# Using cy.log to print out Cypress environment variables

Tags: typescript, cypress, environment

**Goal**: How can I print Cypress environment variables?

**Code**:

```
cy.log(Cypress.env()); // Error: Argument of type 'ObjectLike' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)
```

I understand I can't print it because `cy.log()` takes in a `string` and `Cypress.env()` is of type `ObjectLike`, but I'm not sure what other approach I can take to print it.

Comment: Would converting it to a string with `JSON.stringify(Cypress.env())` work? (or with indentation: `JSON.stringify(Cypress.env(), null, 2)`)

Comment: Also you can check it in the Cypress runner, Settings menu, Configuration option, `env` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typescript error, so you can type the parameter

```js
cy.log(Cypress.env() as any)
```

or use this form `.log(message: string, ...args: any[])`

```js
cy.log('env', Cypress.env())
```

or `Cypress.log()` with options (`options.message` is type `any`)

```js
Cypress.log({ name: 'env', message: Cypress.env() })
```